# Is there a way to use dynamic field like this?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

What I'm doing is method invoking by reflection. Before I invoke some method lets say it's name will be `FooMethod`, I need to create `argument` (type of this argument I know only at runtime). So I was thinking to do it with use of `dynamic` field to pass an values for that `argument`.

**Example:**

```
class SampleClass
{
     public string SomeField{get;set;}
}

class Foo
{
    void Execute(string methodName, dynamic values)
    {
        var type = typeof(SampleClass);
        var method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
        var methodParameterType = method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
        var methodParameterProperties = methodParameterType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        //just for example purpose assume that first property name is SomeField
        if(values[methodParameterProperties[0].Name] != null)
        {
             // build argument here
        }
    }
}
```

**use of that:**

```
dynamic a = new {SomeField = "someValue"};
var fooClass = new Foo();
fooClass.Execute("FooMethod",a);//here I'm getting exception
```

**Exception I getting at the moment:**

```
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
```

**Question:**
How should I do this? Is there a way to allow checking this values with indexing without creating Dictionary?

Comment: What is `FooMethod` ?

Comment: Why not use params instead of dynamic?

Comment: I've made it using classic reflection instead of dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Try use ExpandoObject instead of dynamic. You can't index it, but you can not to create your dictionary.

```
    public void Execute(string methodName, ExpandoObject values)
    {
        // ...

        if(values.Any(x => x.Key == methodParameterProperties[0].Name))
        {
            var value = values.First(x => x.Key == methodParameterProperties[0].Name).Value;
             // build argument here (based on value)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning an instance of an anonymous class with a single field, `SomeField`, to `a`, and then you try to index it as if it's an array. That's not going to work.

However, `MethodInfo.Invoke()` accepts an array of objects as arguments, so there's no need for dynamic here at all. Change the type of your `values` parameter to `object[]` and pass that to `Invoke`. So:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod(string s)
    {
    }
}

public object Execute(object obj, string methodName, object[] arguments)
{
    Type type = obj.GetType();
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName);
    return methodInfo.Invoke(obj, arguments);
}
```

You can also add a `params` specifier to `arguments` so it can be called like:

```
Execute(someObject, "someObjectMethod", arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

You'll need to make sure that the arguments you pass in are of the correct type, otherwise `Invoke` will throw an `ArgumentException`. Also, if the given object doesn't have a method with the given name, `GetMethod` will return null. You may also want to check the number of arguments that the method takes, depending on how and where you intend to use this code.